# Find this somewhat unpleasant limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am solving a problem and after quite some computations and almost 1 day spent on it, I decided to ask here.

It all boils down to finding this limit $$\lim_{x \to 0+}C(x) = ?$$

where

$$C(x) = \frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\cdot \ln \big(\sqrt{x^2+1} + x \big)}{2x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\cdot \ln\big(\sqrt{x^2+1} + x \big)}$$

I applied L'Hôpital's rule a few times to get to here.

Now [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28%20x%20-%20%20ln%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%20%2B%20x%29%20*%20sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29%20%2F%20%28%20%20%20%28%202*x%5E2%20*%20ln%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%20%2B%20x%29%20*%20sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29%20%29%20%20as%20x%20goes%20to%200%2B) says this limit is $$-1/6$$ and this is correct. So I am trying to compute this and derive that $$\lim_{x \to 0+}C(x) = -1/6$$ by hand.

And after studying the sub-expressions, I can see this limit is of the kind $0/0$ but if I try to apply L'Hôpital's rule again to the expression $C(x)$, it doesn't get simpler, it gets more complicated.

So there must be some trick here. Maybe I need to divide the numerator and denominator by some expression. I tried that too a few times but I don't succeed at making it simpler.

Or... is this problem not solvable at all just by using L'Hôpital's rule?
But I don't see what other theory to apply here.

Any help or hint as to how to proceed?

**Side note:** Here is the original problem which led me to this expression $C(x)$. It asks us to find this limit.

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} \left(\frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{x^2} = ?$$

[image: problem]

Comment: This is interesting and I am not sure yet, but here is my first idea:
multiply $x + \sqrt{1+x^2 } $ by $\frac{ \sqrt{1+x^2 } - x }{ \sqrt{1+x^2 } - x }$
I would do this in the original expression.

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty interesting problem. It's from FB, from some senior exam (whatever that means). The answer to the original problem is $e^{-1/6}$

Comment: change variable to $x = \sinh\theta$, the limit you want equals to
$$\lim_{\theta\to0+}\frac{\sinh\theta - \theta\cosh\theta}{2\theta\sinh^2\theta\cosh\theta} = \lim_{\theta\to0+}
\frac{\sinh\theta - \theta\cosh\theta}{2\theta^3}
 $$ and applie  L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @achillehui nice

Comment: @achillehui You mean, I substitute $x=\sinh\theta$ in $C(x)$ or in the original problem?

Comment: $C(x){}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. Are you sure we're getting $2\theta^3$ in the denominator? I mean the second expression in your comment.

Comment: $2\theta^3$ is correct, you essentially multiply the denominator on the left by $\left(\frac{\sinh\theta}{\theta}\right)^2$ and using the fact $\lim_{\theta\to0+} \frac{\sinh\theta}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta\to0+} \cosh\theta = 1$ to replace the denominator by something that gives you the same limit.

Comment: $\sinh^2\theta = (\sinh(\theta))^2$

Comment: @achillehui I see, thanks. For a moment I thought you had $\sinh (\theta^2)$

Comment: @achillehui I was able to compute it till the end, and I indeed got the answer $$-1/6$$ Incredible :) What's even better is that I learnt 2-3 things along the way. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know about logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I am not sure. So probably I don't know :) (at least not in details).

Answer (score 5):

A possible way to "see" the limit is the following.
By Taylor's theorem we have
$$
\log(x + \sqrt{1+x^2}) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + R_5(x)
$$ with a remainder $R_5$.

Therefore,
$$
\left(\frac{\log(x + \sqrt{1+x^2})}{x} \right)^{1/x^2}
= \left(1 - x^2\left(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{R_5(x)}{x^3} \right) \right)^{1/x^2}.
$$

The remainder term $\frac{R_5(x)}{x^3}$ can be bounded by the usual techniques (see e.g. the wikipedia site "Taylor's theorem"). With a sandwhiching argument we can conclude
$$
\lim_{x \to 0+}{\left(\frac{\log(x + \sqrt{1+x^2})}{x} \right)^{1/x^2}}
= \lim_{x \to 0+}{\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{6}\right)}^{1/x^2}
= e^{-1/6}.
$$

Comment: I had this idea too... But how can you apply Taylor provided that the function is not even defined at $x=0$ ?!

Comment: The function _is_ defined at $x = 0$. Notice that we look at $\log(x + \sqrt{1+x^2})$ which has a value of $0 = \log(1) = \log(0 + \sqrt{1+0^2})$, not $\log(x)$.

Comment: Oh, OK, I guess I got totally confused.

Comment: So Taylor's formula can be applied here. That application is correct and rigorous? I did think about applying Taylor's formula here but I wasn't sure if I am allowed to. Can you maybe just elaborate on this sandwiching argument (if you like)? Thank you for your answer too, it's good to have one alternative way of solving a problem.

Comment: Not that plotting tools should be a deciding factor, but it is reassuring that $e^{-\frac{1}{6}}$ appears to agree with a plot of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\lm{\lim_{x\to0^+}}
\def\sq{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
\def\lg{\ln(x+\sq)}
\def\lh{\textrm{l'Hopital's}}$We evaluate the limit, $\lm C(x)$, using l'Hopital's, showing all necessary details.
When verifying the work below, it is useful to notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\lg &= \frac{1}{\sq} \\ 
\frac{d}{dx}\sq &= \frac{x}{\sq}.
\end{align*}
We find
\begin{align*}
\lm C(x) &= \lm \frac{x-\sq\lg}{2x^2\sq\lg} \\
&= \lm \frac{1-\frac{x}{\sq}\lg-\sq\frac{1}{\sq}}{4x\sq\lg+2x^2\frac{x}{\sq}\lg+2x^2\sq\frac{1}{\sq}} & \lh \\
&= \lm \frac{-\frac{x\lg}{\sq}}{\frac{4x(1+x^2)\lg}{\sq}+\frac{2x^3\lg}{\sq}+2x^2} \\
&= \lm \frac{-\frac{x\lg}{\sq}}{2x^2+\frac{(4x+6x^3)\lg}{\sq}} \\ 
&= \lm \frac{-\frac{x\lg}{\sq}}{2x^2+\frac{(4x+6x^3)\lg}{\sq}}
\frac{\frac{\sq}{x}}{\frac{\sq}{x}} \\ 
&= \lm \frac{-\lg}{2x\sq+(4+6x^2)\lg} \\ 
&= \lm \frac{-\frac{1}{\sq}}{2\sq+2x\frac{x}{\sq}+12x\lg+(4+6x^2)\frac{1}{\sq}} & \lh \\
&= -\frac{1}{6}.
\end{align*}